# AS3 SharedObject spooky array entanglement

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, shared-objects

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("example");
var arr:Array=[1,2,3];
so.data.arr = arr;
so.flush();
trace(so.data.arr); // outputs 1,2,3
arr[2]=5;
trace(so.data.arr); // outputs 1,2,5
```

As you see, I updated only **arr**, but **so.data.arr** got updated as well.

**so.data.arr** doesn't update if instead of arr[2]=5; i write arr=[1,2,5];

Seems that **arr** and **so.data.arr** are linked somehow, but only if I update an element in the arr, not set the whole arr differently.

I discovered this accidentally. Why is it working like that?

Can I count that it works like that every time and use it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically speaking arrays are passed by reference, not by value. That means if you assign an array variable to another one you are not creating a new array.

> `so.data.arr = arr;`

means that both `so.data.arr` and `arr` point to the same array object. That's why modifications to either one will be reflected by the other. They are pointing at the same thing. But

> `arr=[1,2,5];`

will make `arr` point to some other array object, remember that `[1,2,5]` is a short hand version of `new Array(1,2,5)`.

That's why after that line they aren't "linked" any more.